# Why is angular momenum related to the spin?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, spinors

What I know about spin ½ particles is that they are represented by spinors, and thus, you need to apply a 720° rotation in order for the spinor to return to its original value. Spin 1 particles are vectors, and their transformation is trivial.

Also, spin ½ have $\frac{\hbar}{2}$ or $-\frac{\hbar}{2}$ angular momentum, while spin 1 have $\hbar$ or $0$ or $-\hbar$ angular momentum.

But why are these related? Why should a particle that transforms like a vector have integer angular momentum, while spinors have half-integer angular momentum? Is it just an observation?

Comment: Related question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/582612/rotation-of-a-spinor?rq=1

Comment: A short answer: if we rotate our 3 dimensional coordinate, we expect a spin-${n \over 2}$ particle to transform according to the rotation. The former transformations are the Lie group $SO(3)$, while the later are the ${n+1}$ dimensional irreducible representation of the Lie group $SU(2)$. If ${n+1}$ is even, the corresponding irreducible representation of $SU(2)$ will be the double cover of $SO(3)$ (for example, $SO(3) \cong SU(2)/ \{\pm I\}$). The property of double cover makes us require $4\pi$ rotation to impose the isomorphism between $SO(3)$ and the corresponding rotations of spin.

Comment: The transformation of vectors is not trivial. The transformation of scalars is trivial.

Comment: I mean it rotates as much as the transformation matrix rotates it

Comment: @AndyChen To post a short answer, please post an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simplified, hand-wavey explanation is to say that in the same way that *linear* momentum is related to one over the wavelength of the wavefunction as you move each *linear* direction, so the *angular* momentum (spin) is related to one over the 'wavelength' (really we need a new word, like 'waveangle' for this idea) of waves as you *rotate* in each *angular* direction. (Have a look at some pictures of the spherical harmonics to see what this looks like. We fit a number of sine-waves 'around' a sphere.) If you spin around in a full circle, you have to be able to fit a whole number of waves into that circle to avoid any discontinuity, so spin is quantised.

With a vector, spinning 360 degrees has to get you back where you started, so the number of angular 'wavelengths' has to be a whole number. With a spinor, spinning 360 reverses sign, and you have to turn 720 degrees to get back where you started. Fitting an odd whole number of angular 'wavelengths' into 720 degrees means fitting a half-integer number into 360 degrees.

Comment: That's actually a quite nice explanation.